# WPF: Get column name from selected row

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq, datagrid

I am trying to get the Row's particular column from selected item in wpf from DataGrid.

Name of DataGrid is `Datagrid_Newsale`.

I am getting alert of whole row when it is selected, So i tried mapping its column.

Say if row is-

```
{ ID = 3, CustomerName = xyz, SaleDate = 05.08.2013 00:00:00, TotalAmount = 10 }
```

Then it's column `CustomerName=xyz` is to be shown in textbox.

**Getting row-**

```
var copyitem = Datagrid_NewSale.SelectedItem;

if (copyitem == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please select values from list");
}
if (copyitem != null)
{                       
    MessageBox.Show(copyitem.ToString());
}
```

For getting customerName into text box i tried creating a new instance of model-

```
public class CustomerDetailes
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

And values from database from Customer Table-

```
public void viewcustomername()
{
    List<CustomerDetailes> ilist = null;
    ilist = (from order in db.Customer
                select new CustomerDetailes
                {
                    CustomerName= order.CustomerName
                }).ToList();
    txtCustumer.Text = ilist.ToString();

}
```

So giving it one more try-

```
CustomerDetailes copyitem = (CustomerDetailes)Datagrid_NewSale.SelectedItem;

if (copyitem == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please select values from list");
}
if (copyitem != null)
{                       
    MessageBox.Show(copyitem.ToString());
}

txtCustomer.text=copyitem.CustomerName;  //CustomerName into a textbox
```

But it is referencing null in copyitem.

How can I get particular column from the whole row.

Comment: @nit, Yes getting whole row as it is described in question.

Comment: @nit, No.., For first try without using model `CustomerDetails`; it is showing full row. But when i used model then it is coming null.

Comment: sorry i did't understand. Did you set the itemsSource of DataGrid to CustomerDetails collection?

Comment: @nit, No I don't know about that, Maybe you wanna post an answer on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this easy solution.

Mapped datatype of `copyitem` that was Anonymous in my case. In this case using `Dynamic` datatype solved my problem.

Due to my data was coming dynamically and then i was trying to map out particular column, so it was not really possible to do it statically because there is not data then.

**Using Dynamic Datatype-**

```
 dynamic copyitem = dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
```

**Accessing property-**

```
int localId = copyitem.ID;
```

furthermore for customerName,TotalAmount i did the same.

**Linq Query changes-**

```
var query= (from order in db.Customer
where order.ID=localId
select order).ToList();
```

`DataGrid_OpenSale.ItemsSource=query` // returning data to another datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to bind the `ItemsSource` of DataGrid to CustomerDetails collection in order to get CustomDetails in SelectedItem.

Create property in your viewmodel (if using MVVM) or in code behind like

```
List<CustomerDetails> customerDetails = new List<CustomerDetails>();
    List<CustomerDetails> MyCollection
    {
        get
        {

            return myList;
        }
        set
        {
            myList = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyCollection"));
        }
    }
```

and in xaml just do.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"/>
```

OR if you are directly filling the Items in the datagrid add instances of CustomerDetails like

```
dataGrid.Items.Add(new CustomerDetails(){Name = "abc"}, xyz propertis)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the grid from your selection event then following should give your the column
`((DataGrid)sender).CurrentCell.Column.Header`

and use some mapping for the column name to the property of the object your want to show

Answer (score 0):

in VB ⠀⠀⠀

```
Private Sub SCUSTDataGrid_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles SCUSTDataGrid.GotFocus
  Dim og As DataGridCell = e.OriginalSource
  Dim ccontent As TextBlock = og.Content
  Dim dg As DataGrid
  dg = e.Source
  Dim selcol As String = dg.CurrentCell.Column.Header.ToString

  MessageBox.Show(selcol.ToString + ccontent.Text + " got focus event")
End Sub
```