# Move Focus to next Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Suppose I have a `DataGrid` and a `Button`. `CanUserAddRows` is set to `True`. Let this dataGrid have two `DataGridTextColumns` namely "Name" and "Age".

Now if user takes the following actions :

1. He adds name as XYZ and Age as 20. Then he press enter. So a new row will be added to the datagrid.
2. He adds name as ABC and Age as 12. Then he press enter. So a new row will be added to the datagrid.
3. He keeps name empty and press Enter or TAB then I want to move focus to `Button` instead of next cell of datagrid.

I have watched many questions but I don't get the logic of if user left the name empty and how do I move focus to Button instead of next cell.

Comment: you can use button.Focus();

Comment: But in which event? What should be the Condition?

Comment: This is fairly complex if I understand it correctly.  You'll need to terminate the DataGrid's add transaction based upon inspection of the bound property, "Name".

Comment: Are you using MVVM or code-behind?  This will help if somebody wants to include code in their answer.

Comment: BTW, the question is more about how to interact with DataGridView than moving the focus (this one being trivial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataGridView.SelectedCells[0]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19231765/3283203) so you can retrieve the value of the selected cell (assuming you can only select one).

To get the actual string inside, you will have to cast the content to a proper WPF object, like TextBlock.
`myCell.Column.GetCellContent(cell.Item) as TextBlock`

Then in a [PreviewKeyDown](http://www.dotnetperls.com/previewkeydown) event handler (KeyDown having [known issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820266/wpf-how-to-handle-keydown-event-for-datagrid) in DataGridView), you can use `button.Focus()`. ([more about those issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747183.aspx#AddingInstanceHandlersthatAreRaisedEvenWhenEventsareMarkedHandled))

```
//...
myDataGrid1.PreviewKeyDown += myDataGrid1_KeyDown;
//...
void myDataGrid1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
    {
        var cell = myDataGrid1.SelectedCells[0];
        TextBlock cellContent = cell.Column.GetCellContent(cell.Item) as TextBlock;
        if (cellContent != null)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(cellContent.Text))
                button.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

About getting the column's name, it's another question, for which you can find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512025/wpf-get-column-name-from-selected-row) for example.

As a side note, you're not really supposed to interact directly with a DataGridView cells' values, since it's meant to be bound with a data source from which you should retrieve the data you want to test. However, you can search a bit for helper methods that can help you [get what you want](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/74332b78-6bfd-4ac9-af85-dfd9bec87a29/get-cell-value-from-wpf-datagrid?forum=wpf).

Comment: what is `cell`? WPF does not recognize it.

Comment: Sorry to say but I get another error : Cannot implicitly convert FrameworkElement to String

Comment: The event is never fired. Here is the sample project https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bZnZtd2doZklUSGs/edit?usp=sharing Please take a look at it when you become free.

Comment: You can also google the issue and tell me what you found. It's apparently a known issue with KeyDown. Gotta use PreviewKeyDown instead. Editing.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have been out of town. I have tried PreviewKeyDown instead of KeyDown as you suggested. Now event fires correctly but `cellContent is always null`.

Comment: Looks like there is an issue about getting content froms cells in DataGridView (values not updated soon enough to get grabbed), so [check the answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464704/get-row-in-datagrid), I'm sure you'll find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a handler for the DataGrid.KeyDown event, as:

```
void myDataGrid1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
    {
        button.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I know that the cell belongs to Name Column and If is this cell is empty or not?